# JavaDoc editor for Eclipse to create formatted text

Tags: html, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, javadoc

im looking for a small plugin which let me create formated javadoc. at the moment im doing it with word (or http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/full.php ) and save the text as a html file which then can be used but i think there must be a easier solution to create nice looking java doc..

Comment: what kind of javadoc are you creating, that you need word to create html? if you are not coming along with P and LI you should probably consider writing a real documentation instead of writing tons of javascript. 

in my optionion, tests, READMEs and example code are way better documentation than bloated javadoc.

Comment: well formated jdoc just looks better and is easier to read..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JDocEditor is an Eclipse plugin that lets you write Javadoc in a WYSIWYG editor window:
http://www.certiv.net/projects/jdoceditor.html

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use this

http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Nice one, just what I always needed :)

Comment: some of the features of jautodoc produce absolutly superfluous jdoc like "The class MyClass" for a class myClass. i would not recommend it for such things..